# How to efficiently copy from gsl::span to std::vector?

Tags: c++, stl, gsl

To copy from a C++20 `std::span` into an `std::vector` I can simply do the following:

```
void WriteBuffer(std::vector<std::byte>& destData, const std::span<const std::byte>& srcData)
{
    std::copy(srcData.begin(), srcData.end(), destData.end());
}
```

..which will be optimised to a single `memmove`. See example: https://godbolt.org/z/8nPjzj3c6

However, if I replace `std::span` with `gsl::span` we don't get this optimisation anymore: https://godbolt.org/z/MWfPKW8eq

Is it best to instead resize the vector and use `std::memcpy` to copy over the data, or are there better alternatives?

My understanding is that `gsl::span` does not get optimised, because it's using a custom iterator that the implementation of `std::copy` is not aware of - so it cannot make assumptions about the linearity of the data - is that right? If so, I suppose all STL containers and algorithms will have the same issue with `gsl::span` and any other data structures that use custom iterators. But please let me know if I've misunderstood something.

**Update:** Sorry, there was a mistake here. As @Caleth kindly pointed out, I'm writing out of bounds. However, resizing first and then using copying to `destData.begin()` (yes overwriting, just for simplicity..) doesn't really change it - it still copies byte-by-byte.

Comment: Writing to `destData.end()` is undefined anyway.  You need something like `std::back_inserter(destData)` or to to `resize` the vector first and copy starting at the position where `end` used to be (but that requires zero-initializing the newly-expanded locations and possible re-allocating the vector).

Comment: `std::copy` can have specialization for `std::span` iterators and obviously there can't be such specialization for iterators form `gsl::span`.

Comment: BTW, last argument is obviously wrong: `std::copy(srcData.begin(), srcData.end(), destData.end());`!

Comment: OT: Does it makes any sense to pass `std::span` by reference?

Comment: @DanielLangr No that was silly, thanks for pointing it out :) It should have been passed by value.

Comment: Note that in the `gsl::span` case, "it" doesn't "copy byte-by-byte". Vectorization/SIMD instructions are used when you specify the target architecture: https://godbolt.org/z/hT84b81ME. Then, it is questionable whether `memmove` woudl be even faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> because it's using a custom iterator that the implementation of std::copy is not aware of

Not really. The standard library would see [this member](https://github.com/microsoft/GSL/blob/52212c2d7600c816ec9b0438d3fbd2a95c190c2f/include/gsl/span#L119) and have the same knowledge about the data layout.

```
#if defined(__cpp_lib_ranges) || (defined(_MSVC_STL_VERSION) && defined(__cpp_lib_concepts))
    using iterator_concept = std::contiguous_iterator_tag;
#endif // __cpp_lib_ranges
```

The more likely reason is that the iterator operations are checked at runtime, rather than the "undefined behaviour when misused" of `std::span`.

If you were to read out of range of `srcData`, using `std::span` the behaviour is undefined. Using `gsl::span`, the behaviour is defined, `std::terminate` is called. The "missing optimisations" are probably because `memcpy`ing out of range data is not the same as calling `std::terminate`

Your example code exhibits undefined behaviour when `srcData` has any elements, because you can't write past the end of a vector.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! You're right, I'm writing out of range - which is a mistake. However, if I resize the vector first and copy to `destData.begin()` instead it's still the same:https://godbolt.org/z/Mdxa3q9v1

See LBB0_13, which seems to just loop and copy each byte? (and as you say, calls std::terminate if we end up writing out of range)

Comment: It really seems that the "missing optimization" is caused by the range-checking in the GSL source code: https://github.com/microsoft/GSL/blob/52212c2d7600c816ec9b0438d3fbd2a95c190c2f/include/gsl/span#L144. I tried to replicate this problem with a custom code: https://godbolt.org/z/Ts7onWej4. Once the check in line #27 is removed, `memmove` call is generated.

Comment: @MyNiceDisplayName yes, my point is that `gsl::span` has different semantics to `std::span`, which means different optimisations are possible

Comment: Aha, that makes sense then. Thanks a lot for pointing this out for me! And for the example @DanielLangr

Comment: Just for curiosity's sake, I wondered whether there is some way how to allow a compiler to generate `memcpy` instead of `memmove` for the `std::span` case. This doesn't seem to be possible now, but I've found this proposal: https://kokkos.github.io/array_ref/proposals/P0856.html.